# rspec 2 to 3 syntax stub error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am converting a bunch of spec's from rspec 2 to 3 syntax.

there is this particular stub.

`mail.stub(deliver: mail)`

I have tried several things to get this to the new syntax but I am struggling a bit.

I have tried

`allow(mail).to receive(deliver: mail)`

Which will result in an

```
undefined method `to_sym' for {:deliver=>#<Double "mail">}:Hash
```

any help with this particular stub would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a stub you can add a return block, ignoring the passed arguments, like so:

```
allow(mail).to receive(:deliver) { 'hello' }
```

If its an expectation you can use the #with method to verify arguments:

```
expect(mail).to receive(:deliver).with(mail) { 'hello' }
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs

Comment: Thanks, @Puhlze That seemed to do the job :)